# Django query to combine two tables without aggregation

Tags: django

I want to write a django query and avoid raw sql doing the following:

Lets imaging I have those two tables resulting from django query (query under the table):

Table 1:

| Name | Count |
| --- | --- |
| First | 4 |
| Second | 7 |
| Third | 2 |
| Fourth | 12 |
| Fith | 5 |

Query:

```
q1 = Entity.objects.filter(some_condition=1)\
    .values(
    "name",
).annotate(Count("name"))
```

Table 2:

| Name | Count |
| --- | --- |
| First | 13 |
| Second | 6 |
| Third | 2 |
| Fourth | 12 |
| Sixth | 3 |

Query:

```
q2 = Entity.objects.filter(some_condition=2)\
    .values(
    "name",
).annotate(Count("name"))
```

What I want to achieve is the following table using just Django query:

| Name | Count table 1 | Count table 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | 4 | 13 |
| Second | 7 | 6 |
| Third | 2 | 2 |
| Fourth | 12 | 12 |
| Fith | 5 | 0 |
| Sixth | 0 | 3 |

Two solutions seems to solve it but didn't work. If I use

```
3 = (q1 | q2)
```

the column "count" will be aggregated and there will be just one count column.
If I'm using

```
q1.union(q2)
```

I get the error message:
*django.db.utils.DatabaseError: ORDER BY not allowed in subqueries of compound statements.*

Comment: Havent tested this, but try something like: `Entity.objects.annotate(count_table_1=Count('name', filter=Q(some_condition=1).annotate(count_table_2=Count('name', filter=Q(some_condition=2)`

Comment: Works perfectly as needed. Thank you.